# Create a tutorial in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I’m trying to create a terminal python program. I want to add a tutorial for the user when they first launch the program and then never have it open again. Is there any way to do this, or do I have to create a separate script for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to do this. You could simply create a file when the program is launched for the first time.

```
first_time=False
fn='config.txt'
try:
    file = open(fn, 'r')
except IOError:
    file = open(fn, 'w')
    first_time=True
if(first_time):
    print("This is the first time")
    #you tutorial code can go here
```